# Is there a way to use custom components on headers in material-table?

Tags: reactjs, material-table

Is there a way to use custom components on headers in material-table? Unlike the data cells where you can use the `render: rowData => ()` function, I can't seem to find a way to change the header cells into a custom component. Thank you very much!

[As per request, here's a screenshot of what it currently looks like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOcF7.png)

What I want to accomplish is having the **SCHEDULE**, **BREAKFAST**, **LUNCH**, and **DINNER** column headers to have some extra components instead of having it as a text.

Something like these:

```
         SCHEDULE
SUN-MON-TUE-WED-THU-FRI-SAT
```

```
 BREAKFAST
05:00-07:00
```

and here's a sample code on how to set the header titles currently:

```
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    columns: [
      {
        title: "MEAL",
        field: "meal",
        headerStyle: {
          textAlign: "left"
        },
        render: rowData => (
          <Link to={"/meals"} className={classes.mealNamesLink}>
            {rowData.meal}
          </Link>
        )
      },
      {
        title:"SCHEDULE",
        field: "schedule",
        headerStyle: {
          textAlign: "left"
        },
        cellStyle: {
          margin: 0,
          padding: 0
        },
```

as you can see, I managed to make the content cells into a custom component using the `render` method on the **Meals** column, but I can't seem to change the headers into a custom component because it is set via `title:`

Comment: Can you put some code or how output should look like ? any lead for the above problem

Comment: Hi @Krina Soni, I have updated the question. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually... you know what... I'm really sorry but apparently the fix was just to put it on the `title:` straight. No mumbo jumbos.

For example:

```
title: <p> I am really dumb for not knowing this </p>
```

I'm gonna close it now, but here is the answer for those who may find themselves in a conundrum such as I did (I doubt it).

Comment: You can also make a array and map through each elements in one const variable, which you can directly pass to the title.

Comment: Thank you for this! So simple it hurts that I took hours looking for this answer.